# HP 15-dw0037wm - Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCI-E Wireless Network Adapter Issues - Not Working in Linux - Ubuntu/Debian/Pop OS!

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, 20.10

I have an issue getting the following laptop's wireless adapter working properly with Linux(AKA Ubuntu).

HP 15-dw0037wm - Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCI-E Wireless Network Adapter

I was wondering if someone could provide a clear, step by step, guide that would allow me to get this adapter working properly. It also functions as a Bluetooth receiver and I would really like for both the Wireless Connection Functionality and the Bluetooth Connection Functionality to work as intended.

Could someone shed some light as to why this card isn't working properly after a fresh install like almost every other wireless adapter I've ever had to work with when installing Linux? Is the adapter just too new? Is it using some proprietary design and isn't Linux friendly?

If you need any info from me just let me know and I will try to collect that info for you as soon as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

====

Edit 12/31/2020 - Apparently canonical have created a package they maintain for this scenario.

To install it simply open a terminal and enter the following command...

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Remember I was trying to get both wi-fi and bluetooth working so if one works but not the other, that means I am still having issues and this isn't working. Anyway I will let you guys know what happens in a few days when I touch the laptop again to work on it.

====

Edit 12/31/2020 #2 - After reading up some more I found this thread...

https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/94

In this thread they reference this package...

https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-realtek

So I will try installing this package as well to see if that corrects the issue and provides both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi functionality.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-firmware && sudo apt install firmware-realtek && sudo apt autoremove && sudo reboot
```

I will let you guys know how it goes in a few days when I can try it.

Comment: What OS & release, you mention 3 OSes (two of which are off-topic on this site; refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and 2 releases.

Comment: Let's just go with plain Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 20.10. Again I just really want the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth to work as intended. I would love to use Pop_OS! instead as I find they take care of a lot of stuff Ubuntu doesn't and it's an Ubuntu based derivative anyway but, I would be happy just sticking to regular old Ubuntu as long as the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth work without trouble. I would like to stream audio over Bluetooth to a large Bluetooth speaker I have setup in the living room.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have found that the Realtek RTL8821CE wireless devices will not work with any Linux distribution while “Secure Boot” is enabled in the BIOS. This setting is not a requirement for you computers to work, and it does not make a device any more secure. Disabling it should not result in any consequences.

Comment: I have already disabled secure boot. I still do not have the Bluetooth functionality. I have made some edits to my original question that shed some light on this topic and might have the answer I am looking for I just need time and a chance to try it. I will let you guys know how it goes in a few days when I can touch and work on the laptop again. Wish me luck